# mod rewrite redirects to base link when href="hashtag"

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the link

```
<a href='#' class='changer text-primary'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o '></i></a>
```

to edit inline the value of product quantity using javascript. It used to work fine until I implemented the mod redirect inside my application.
I added the base link : `<base href="http://127.0.0.1/MyApp/">`
Now when I click over this link I got redirected to http://127.0.0.1/MyApp/index.php instead of staying in the same page and displaying the form of update via jquery toggle.

this is the update form:

```
<form class="update-quantity-form" style="display: none">
   <div class="input-group updater">
      <input name="quantity" value="<?= $saved_cart_items[$id_product]['quantity']?>" min="1" class="form-control" required="" type="number">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default update-quantity">Update</button>
       </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is the content of htaccess relatif to this file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^MyCart/?$  cart.php [NC,L]
```

This is the javascript of the toggle animation that have been ignored:

```
$('.changer').on('click', function () {
   $('.update-quantity-form').toggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Then don't use a link element where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I may need them. Is there no solution for this problem?

Comment: remove the `MyApp/` from it, then just add the folder to the link itself, *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: plus, why did you tag as javascript, jquery, mod-rewrite and htaccess with no code to support the question? base href isn't a mod-rewrite. Post relevant code to the tags.

Comment: *I'm out of this loop*.

Comment: Have updated the needed code to support the question tags @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with mod_rewrite, .htaccess or even your html itself.

The problem is that your javascript event handler does not properly cancel the navigation when no navigation is required. Even without your problem with `<base ...>`, in all browsers a hashtag will appear behind the url, and in some browsers the focus will snap to the top of the screen.

Instead, use the following javascript to cancel the navigation event:

```
$('.changer').on( 'click', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.update-quantity-form').toggle('fast');
} );
```

For more information, see [the click event on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click), which is a MouseEvent, which is an UIEvent, which is an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), which implements [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).